# Make type of vector arbitrary

Tags: c++, vector, c++17

I'm currently implementing a simple stack in c++17, which has to have a `toString`-Method, that can deal among other types with `std::vector` as the template type.

My original problem was, that `std::to_string` can't accept vector's to I added a specialized implementation for vector's on top of my normal implementation:

```cpp
template <class T> std::string SweCpp::Stack<T>::toString()
{
    std::string result = "SweCpp::Stack[";

    for (int a = 0; a < top + 1; a++)
    {
        T element = st[a];

        result += std::to_string(element);

        if (a != top) {
            result += ", ";
        }
    }
    result += "]";
    return result;
}


template <> std::string SweCpp::Stack<std::vector<double>>::toString() {
    std::string result = "SweCpp::Stack[";

    for (int a = 0; a < top + 1; a++)
    {
        std::vector<double> element = st[a];

        std::string vecAsString = "Vector{";
        for (double value : element) {
            vecAsString += std::to_string(value) + ",";
        }
        vecAsString += "}";

        result += vecAsString;
        if (a != top) {
            result += ", ";
        }
    }
    result += "]";
    return result;
}
```

The idea is to call `to_string` for every element of the vectors, and build a string like that. The problem is, that I can't figure out, how to make the `double` arbitrary. How can I implement it, so that I can pass any type of vector, e.g. `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<std::string>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template <typename T>
std::string MyToString(const T& val) {
  return std::to_string(val);
}

template <typename T>
std::string MyToString(const std::vector<T>& vec) {
  std::string vecAsString = "Vector{";
  for (const auto& value : vec) {
    vecAsString += MyToString(value) + ",";
  }
  vecAsString += "}";
  return vecAsString;
}
```

Now implement `Stack<T>::toString()` as in your first example, but call `MyToString` in place of `std::to_string`